# How do I fix this discards qualifiers error?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a list of chores based on their priority by using the STL priority queue. When I try to compile I receive and error about both the output function, and the overloaded < operator. Ive tried making the functions const, but that didn't fix the issue. How can I fix this?

main.cc

```
priority_queue<Chore> chores;
Chore tmp;

for(int  i = 5; i >0; i--) {
  tmp.input(cin);
  chores.push(tmp);
}

while(!chores.empty()) {
  chores.top().output();
  chores.pop();
}

return 0;

};
```

chore.h

```
class Chore {
  public:
    Chore();
    void input(istream& ins);
    void const output();
    bool const operator <(const Chore c1);

  private:
    string chore_name;
    int priority;
};
```

chore.cc

```
Chore:: Chore() {
  chore_name = "";
  priority = 0;
};

void Chore:: input(istream& ins) {
  cout << "Please Enter the name of the chore: ";
  cin >> chore_name;
  cout << endl << "Please Enter The Priority Level: ";
  cin >> priority;
  cout << endl;
};

void const Chore:: output() {
  cout << "Chore: " <<  chore_name << endl;
  cout << "Priority: " << priority << endl << endl;
};

bool const Chore:: operator <(const Chore c1) {
   return (priority < c1.priority);
};
```

Comment: what is the compiler error ?

Comment: I am a bit confused about your code. Shouldnt it be `void Chore::output() const {...` ?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't making the member functions const. Do it like this:

```
class Chore {
    ...
    void output() const;
    bool operator<(const Chore& c1) const; //Also added pass by reference here
};
void Chore::output() const {...}
bool Chore::operator<(const Chore& c1) const {...}
```

Comment: It immediately compiled. Thank You very much! Would you mind explaining why my code was wrong and what my code was actually accomplishing when it was being interpreted by the compiler?

Comment: Having const before the function name affects the return type. The compiler actually ignores a const return type if it isn't a pointer or reference (returning const bool is equivalent to returning bool). I would have expected it to complain about returning const void though as that makes no sense.